# Converting an integer list macro to string using GCC's C

Tags: c, gcc

I have a macro which is a list of integers that I use to initialize some const arrays. I'd like to use it also as an string and I have not been able to make it work:

```c
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#define MY_NUMBERS 0xA5,0x5A,0x93,0x39,0xF0,0xF0,0x00,0xFF

#define MYSTRING "this is my list: " STR(MY_NUMBERS)

printf(MYSTRING);
```

I would expect this to print "this is my list 0xA5,0x5A...". Instead I get this error when compiling:

```
error: macro "STR_HELPER" passed 8 arguments, but takes just 1
```

I tried this code instead:

```c
printf("second method result: " str((MYSTRING)) )
```

And I get this printed, but I'd like to avoid the parentheses getting printed:

```
second method result: (0xA5,0x5A...
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution using variadic args!

```c
#define STR_HELPER(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STR(...) STR_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MY_NUMBERS 0xA5,0x5A,0x93,0x39,0xF0,0xF0,0x00,0xFF

#define MYSTRING "this is my list: " STR(MY_NUMBERS)

printf(MYSTRING);
```